# Trapezium without border-color

Tags: html, css, svg, shapes

I want to create two trapezoids in css.I can not use the border color because I want to give shapes background-image. Everything should explain the picture. In both div will put i some text.

Can I use html, css, js, svg just do not know how.

[http://iv.pl/images/82062332573614452824.jpg http://iv.pl/images/32788252576166741527.jpg](http://iv.pl/images/32788252576166741527.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in pure CSS through the usage of the `:after` pseudo element.

Basically, I created two rectangles. Then I overlayed a triangle on the right rectangle which was added via the `:after` pseudo element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/GXtJY/) - looks the same

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}

#one {
    background: green;
    width: 130px;
}

#two {
    background: red;
    width: 70px;
}

#two:after {
    content: "\A";
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 45px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: -45px;
}

#wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Instead of two colors I put there two images (background-size: cover). In addition, I have to add # left: hover and # right: hover with the other two photos.

Comment: @user2950873 You can do that, I supplied you with the coding.

Comment: How can I change the border-right: 45px solid red on the picture?

Comment: @user2950873 Making another solution. Give me a minute

Comment: I think it will be good. 'll Check and let you know. Thanks a lot.